# negating multiple conditions as whole or individually in a While loop

Tags: javascript, while-loop, multiple-conditions, negation

I am trying to understand why the below code does not work even though a variation of it works. My understanding eventually both mean the same thing.(I am pretty sure I am wrong, but don't know why)

this works

```
while (!(luc === 'rock' || luc === 'paper' || luc === 'scissor')) {
```

this does not work

```
while (luc !== 'rock' || luc !== 'paper' || luc !== 'scissor')) {
```

Here is complete context

```
var uc = prompt('Choose between Rock, Paper and Scissor')
var luc = uc.toLowerCase();
while (!(luc === 'rock' || luc === 'paper' || luc === 'scissor')) {
  var uc = prompt('You did not select between rock paper and scissor')
  var luc = uc.toLowerCase();
}
console.log(uc)
```

Comment: its `!=` not `!==`. Try `!=` it will work. AND you have an extra `)` at the end of the while statement. Do this `while (luc != 'rock' || luc != 'paper' || luc != 'scissor')`

Comment: This might help you understand the logic of the statements https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws

Answer (score 0):

the or operator (||) looks if either condition is truthy. So the case that works for you is looking for whether the user input is either rock, paper, or scissors and then negates that value.

The second case looks for example if the input is not rock. Lets assume that the input is scissor (valid input) but the check for is not rock will true and thus the entire or chain will evaluate to true due to at least one truthy value present.